# How to fire certain action before and after every ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery and jQuery UI. I experienced that users sometimes fire the ajax-calls more than once, because the button/Link that triggers the call is not disabled right after they click it. To prevent that from happen, I now disable the button/link in my "beforeSend" -action.

This is what a typical Ajax Call looks like for me:

```
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "someURL"
      data: "someDataString",
      beforeSend: function(msg){
        $(".button").button("disable");
      },
      success: function(msg){
        $(".button").button("enable");
        // some user Feedback
      }
    });
```

But I dont wann to add this button-Disable logic in every Ajax Call. Is there any way to globally define a function that gets called everytime before /after and ajax-call?

Comment: Which version of jQuery do/must you use?

Comment: I'm using the latest versions: jQuery 1.5 and jQueryUI 1.8

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve what you are asking for. The only difference between them is how they are implemented, and it's up to you to choose which method works best for your specific case. The methods also depend on which version of jQuery you are using, so I will split this answer into two sections.

#### For jQuery 1.5 and later

**Adding multiple callbacks after init**

Since jQuery 1.5 you can add multiple callbacks thanks to the overhauled API and newly introduced [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqxhr) object that is returned by `.ajax`. It implement the Promise (see [Deferreds](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)) interface, and we can use that to our advantage:

```
// fn to handle button-toggling
var toggleButton = function() {
    var button = $(".button");
    button.button(button.button("option", "disabled") ? "enable" : "disable");
}

// store returned jqXHR object in a var so we can reference to it
var req = $.ajax({
    beforeSend: toggleButton,
    success: function(msg){
        /* Do what you want */
    }
}).success(toggleButton);

// we can add even more callbacks
req.success(function(){ ... });
```

**Using a prefilter**

jQuery 1.5 also introduced [prefilters](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxprefilter/) which you can use to replace the global configuration of jQuery 1.4:

```
// good practice: don't repeat yourself, especially selectors
var button = $(".button");

$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, _, jqXHR) {
    button.button("disable");
    jqXHR.complete(function() {
        button.button("enable");
    });
});
```

Note: The [jqXHR section of the $.ajax entry](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) has this notice about using `jqXHR.success()`:

> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and
>   jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare
>   your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(),
>   and jqXHR.always() instead.

#### For jQuery 1.4 and earlier

**Events and global configuration**

Use [`.ajaxStart`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [`.ajaxStop`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) to bind callbacks to a specific selector. The events that trigger these callbacks will fire off on all Ajax requests.

```
$(".button").ajaxStart(function(){
    $(this).button("disable");
}).ajaxStop(function(){
    $(this).button("enable");
});
```

Use [`.ajaxSetup`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) to setup a global ajax configuration. The settings object passed to `.ajaxSetup` will be applied to all Ajax requests, even those made by the shorthands `.get`, `.getJSON` and `.post`. Note that this isn't recommended since it can easily clobber its functionality.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(){
        $(".button").button("disable");
    },
    success: function(){
        $(".button").button("enable");
    }
});
```

**Filter out requests in global event callbacks**

If you need to filter out certain requests you can do that with[`.ajaxSend`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/) and [`.ajaxComplete`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) where you can check the Ajax `settings` object. Something like this:

```
var button = $(".button");

// fn to handle filtering and button-toggling
var toggleButton = function(settings) {
    if (settings.url == "/specific/url")
        button.button(button.button("option", "disabled") ?
            "enable" : "disable");
    }
};

// bind handlers to the callbacks
button.ajaxSend(function(e,x,settings){
    toggleButton(settings);
}).ajaxComplete(function(e,x,settings){
    toggleButton(settings);
});
```

This can also be done with the previously mentioned `.ajaxSetup` by doing the same type of checks to the `settings` object that is passed to the callback handlers.

Answer (score 6):

To register them **globally** use the

[ajaxStart](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) or [ajaxSend](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/) events

together with the

[ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) or [ajaxStop](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) event

```
$(".button").ajaxStart(function(){
      $(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
});


$(".button").ajaxStop(function(){
      $(this).attr("disabled","");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can set defaults for all ajax calls by calling this function for each page: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/

Also, if there is an ajax call that you don't want to use the default, then simply define that option for that particular ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and bind an eventhandler to the submit event and call an action every time the submit action is called. Read about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/). Otherwise [AjaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) is another good way to do the trick.