# Disable buttons until the task is finished jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have applied click event on a number of li elements like this

```
jQuery('ul li').click(function(){

   doSomething();

});
```

Now I have the requirement where until doSomething is finished. I want the other li elements except the one which is clicked to be disabled and not allow clicks. The doSomething is basically a ajax call.

Comment: make ajax sync, add async:false to ajax parameters

Comment: This would give you an idea how to do it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898381/how-to-fire-certain-action-before-and-after-every-ajax-call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
var lock = false;

jQuery('ul li').click(function(){
   if(lock == true){
      return false; 
   }
   lock = true;
   doSomething();

});
```

When doSomething is done set `lock = false;`

For example:

```
success: function(){
   // your ajax success code 
   lock = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a flag and a ajax complete callback

```
var doing = false;
jQuery('ul li').click(function () {
    if (doing) {
        return;
    }
    doing = true;
    doSomething(function () {
        doing = false;
    });
});

function doSomething(complete) {
    $.ajax().always(complete)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

answer:

```
$(function(){
   $("ul.a li").click(function(){
     $(this).show();//disable true condition write here
     $(this).siblings().hide();//disable false condition write here
});
});
```

Comment: I think my question is how do i disable an li element. Its not button and it still clickable. So how do i unbind the event from other li's